# Set retention for SQL backup to URL

Tags: sql-server, ola-hallengren

I am using [Ola Hallengrens DatabaseBackup script](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html). I am storing my backups in Azure Blob storage using the @url parameter. Everything is working fine, however I am looking for a way to set a retention policy on those backups - currently I assume they live there forever until I manually delete them. I tried using the @CleanupTime parameter but got the following error

```
The value for the parameter @CleanupTime is not supported
```

Is there any way I am able to set this?

Edit: SQL being run for the backup

```
sqlcmd -E -S $(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(SRVR)) -d DBATools -Q \ 
"EXECUTE [dbo].[DatabaseBackup] \ 
@Databases = 'USER_DATABASES', \ 
@BackupType = 'LOG', \ 
@Verify = 'Y',  \
@Compress = 'Y', \ 
@CheckSum = 'Y', \ 
@LogToTable = 'Y', \ 
@ChangeBackupType='Y', \
@url='https://example.blob.core.windows.net/backups', \ 
Credential='AzureBlobBackups'" -b
```

Comment: Can you please share the backup script or that's URL??

Comment: I have linked to the script and edited the question to show the SQL that I am running

Comment: The `@CleanupTime` does not exist in your command...what did you try setting it to?

Comment: Oops, I had it set to 48. However in Ola's script I see the error is thrown in this if statement: IF CleanupTime < 0 OR (CleanupTime IS NOT NULL AND URL IS NOT NULL). Seems like it does not support setting a retention policy when using a URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to clean up files in Azure blob storage requires PowerShell or going through some app like [Azure Explorer](http://www.red-gate.com/products/azure-development/azure-explorer/). So it is likely that Ola's backup script does not support it since there is no native T-SQL command or procedure to access blob storage in that manner.

When you are deleting files you will need to account for any that may still have an active lease. [BOL has code to handle dropping the active leases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj919145.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using XP_Delete_File as your solution.

Here is a link to the scripting and use of it.
[Link](http://www.patrickkeisler.com/2012/11/how-to-use-xpdeletefile-to-purge-old.html)

Xp_delete_file takes five parameters:

1.File Type = 0 for backup files or 1 for report files.

2.Folder Path = The folder to delete files.  The path must end with a backslash "\".

3.File Extension = This could be 'BAK' or 'TRN' or whatever you normally use.

4.Date = The cutoff date for what files need to be deleted.

5.Subfolder = 0 to ignore subfolders, 1 to delete files in subfolders.

Here is the sample script to loop through and delete backups.

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50); -- Database name

DECLARE @path VARCHAR(256); -- Path for backup files 

DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(256); -- Filename for backup 

DECLARE @fileDate VARCHAR(20); -- Used for file name

DECLARE @DeleteDate DATETIME = DATEADD(wk,-1,GETDATE()); -- Cutoff date




-- Path to backups.

SET @path = 'D:\Backup\';




-- Get date to include in file name.

SELECT @fileDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),112);




-- Dynamically get each database on the server.

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 

SELECT name 

FROM master.sys.databases

WHERE name NOT IN ('master','model','msdb','tempdb');




OPEN db_cursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name;




-- Loop through the list to backup each database.

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN  

      -- Build the path and file name.

      SET @fileName = @path + @name + '_' + @fileDate + '.BAK';

      -- Backup the database.

      BACKUP DATABASE @name TO DISK = @fileName WITH INIT;

      -- Loop to the next database.

      FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name;

END  




-- Purge old backup files from disk.

EXEC master.sys.xp_delete_file 0,@path,'BAK',@DeleteDate,0;




-- Clean up.

CLOSE db_cursor;

DEALLOCATE db_cursor;

GO
```

Comment: You might want to read that question one more time....`xp_delete_file` does not work against Azure blob storage.

Comment: Gotcha.  I was treating it as regular maintenance.